# Is there an efficient way to compute Hamming distances between every possible column in a binary matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, sparse-matrix, hamming-distance, pairwise-distance

In NumPy, the command `numpy.corrcoef(X.T)` is amazingly efficient at computing correlations between every possible pair of columns in a matrix `X`. I am looking for a similarly efficient method to compute *Hamming* distances between every possible column of a binary matrix `B`. Is there a NumPy method that I can adapt to do this?

I tried using SciPy's `spatial.distance.pdist(X, metric = 'hamming')`, but it is 100x slower than NumPy's pairwise correlation function.

Following @frank-yellin 's comment, I also tried `spatial.distance.pdist(X, metric = 'cityblock')`, but this only sped up the calculation by 1.7x - which is great, but I am looking for a ~100x speed up if possible.

```
import random
import numpy as np
from scipy import spatial
import time

binary_matrix = np.random.randint(0,2,(1000,1500),dtype = 'int32')
start = time.time()
hamming_with_scipy = spatial.distance.pdist(binary_matrix.T, metric = 'hamming')
end = time.time()
print(f'Hamming takes {end-start} seconds with scipy')

start = time.time()
corr_with_numpy = np.corrcoef(binary_matrix.T)
end = time.time()
print(f'Correlation takes {end-start} seconds with numpy')
```

Output:

```
Hamming takes 5.301102876663208 seconds with scipy
Correlation takes 0.03205609321594238 seconds with numpy
```

Comment: Since your data is already 0 or 1, you might try 'cityblock` instead of 'hamming'.  Same results, but multiplied by the number of elements.

Comment: Thanks! Using 'cityblock' instead of 'hamming' cut the time by 1.7x, but it is still a lot slower than NumPy's implementation of pairwise correlation

Comment: Drop down to C/C++. Asking for two orders of magnitude in time reduction is dubious in Python even with Numpy.

Comment: One remark (not an answer; it doesn't change the fact that `corrcoeff` complexity is apparently not the same as `pdist`), is that `corrcoeff` makes use of all cores of your machine, while `pdist` isn't. Set env variables `MKL_NUM_THREADS=1`, `NUMEXPR_NUM_THREADS=1`, `OMP_NUM_THREADS=1`, to makes meaningful comparisons.

Comment: Most ways to speed up the distance matrix past the point `pdist` can give you depend on the follow-on processes.  If you're going to look up the distance later but don't need it full tabulated now, or want o look for nearest neighbors, `KDTree` data structures might help.

Comment: The problem you are facing is the CPU cache. The numpy function leverages the `BLAS` implementation of `matmul` (actually `gemm`) to perform the "outer product and contraction" in a CPU cache friendly way. The SciPy implementation is "vectorized" however it is cache agnostic and therefore is limited by RAM speed (a 100 times slow down typically).  

If you really _need_ this to go faster you should read about cache friendly algorithms or start with a good implementation and adapt it. One can be found in here https://akkadia.org/drepper/cpumemory.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I just used `pdist` with a custom function `my_hamming` and decorated that with `numba`. I get quite accurately the same time usage. There is probably not much potential in using a low level language. I suspect this rather to be an issue of computational complexity, and indeed:

[image: Complexity]

The correlation coefficients are calculated in quadratic time (slope is 2 decades on time axis to 1 decade on size axis for larger sizes), while the distance computing is cubic (slope 3).

I think it applies to most distances, as they require iterating over all elements of the column vectors.

So in conclusion, these algorithms are not comparable.
To some degree, you might be able to accelerate this via parallel processing - but only by a constant factor (max #CPUs).

Comment: Thanks for trying this out! I assume you're not trying to show that the Hamming distance pairwise computations are fundamentally "harder" than the corresponding correlation coefficient computation (i.e. in terms of time complexity). Both require iterating over every possible column, and looking at the formulae involved, calculating correlations seems to involve more steps. Instead, what I think you're showing is that the issue is with the algorithm used (by scipy) to calculate the Hamming pairwise distances. If so, that is precisely why I made this post - I am looking for a better algorithm.

Comment: Well, the distance needs quadratic time to work on each combination, and that times linear complexity for iterating through the columns to calculate a single distance. Being open for surprises, I fear this cannot be reduced. For the correlation coefficients, there is also a cubic operation to start with, but it can be expressed as a matrix multiplication (`A*A.T`), and this can be / is implemented more efficiently. 

The question (a bit as you say) is then: Is it possible to exploit similar tricks in the Hamming distance calculation, in particular as your matrix is just zeros and ones.

Comment: Can you include the code you used for a Numba implementation of `my_hamming()`?

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't save the code, and now I was travelling for some days. It wasn't magic, just implemented the distance function and decorated it with the numba decorator `njit`.